# Popping up a window after clicking on a date in DatePicker or Calendar

Tags: android, colors, datepicker, calendar, popup

I'm trying to create a work schedule calendar, allowing people to set a day/evening/night shift on the calendar.

When clicking on a date (either in DatePicker or CalendarView, whichever works best), I need a window to pop-up, so you can choose which shift to add to that date through checkboxes or a dropdown menu.

Most resources I found specify how to pop-up a DatePickerDialog when you click on a button, but my DatePicker is already active in the Activity.

After choosing a shift and pressing OK, I need to color the background of that individual date accordingly in the DatePicker, to show that you've already selected a shift for that date.

I've been searching online for an answer for hours, but I can't find anything that works.

This is the standard java file that is created by Android Studio:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    }
}
```

And this is the xml file I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.japiek.testapp.CalendarActivity">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="431dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Right now I'm using the DatePicker instead of a CalendarView as that seemed like the obvious choice when clicking on a date and wanting something to happen afterwards. But I'm not sure if I can color the background of individual dates when using this...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I managed to get the popup thing working by switching from DatePicker to CalendarView and simply setting an onSetDateChangeListener to it. Any help with coloring individual dates would still be greatly appreciated!

EDIT2: Managed to get the color thing working by using MaterialCalendarView instead of CalendarView and using addDecorator in combination with OnDateChangeListener. However, I think icons instead of colors would look better, but how can I add that instead? I tried Drawables, PictureDrawables, and I keep getting No Such File or Directory errors.

EDIT3: Nevermind, I managed that too!